# how to find if a string has multiple phrases but in different order and cannot have more phrases or less and can have spaces in between

Tags: php, regex, string

say for example I have a the following strings

```
$a = "crt d a e f b";
$b = "b e a d c f";
$c = "a b c d g e";
$d = "a b c";
$e = "abcdef";
$f = "a b c d e r f t";
$g = "aabc d e f";
```

All i want to find is if my string is having "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "r", "t" where the string must not have anything other than the specified strings and the string must have all the specified strings in it may can separated by spaces.

maybe something like say `compare($a, [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "r", "t" ];` should give me the output as follows.

```
$map = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "r", "t" ];;
compare($a, $map); // false
compare($b, $map); // false
compare($c, $map); // false
compare($d, $map); // false
compare($e, $map); // false
compare($f, $map); // true
compare($g, $map); // false
```

Can anyone help me out to solve this?

Comment: can a string be repeated more than once?

Comment: no.. only once.. I will add that to the question.. thanks for mentioning.

Comment: Can you demonstrate any effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: @ScottHunter : I know how to match out single string, split out the spaces, and even checking for one time occurrences. but don't have the idea of shuffled words. A regular expression will be helpful, if you know any.

Comment: Are "phrases" limited to a single character?

Comment: one more question, can the phrases in $map have spaces in them? i think you should go towards a programmatical solution, because a regex here, apart from being complex, will have to be build programatically too if you want to use a $map that can change. I'll give a try if i have time.

Comment: @ScottHunter : I have figured out the solution, thanks for the motivation..:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could create an array out of the strings, sort and compare them.

```
$a = "crt d a e f b";
$b = "b e a d c f";
$c = "a b c d g e";
$d = "a b c";
$e = "abcdef";
$f = "a b c d e r f t";
$g = "aabc d e f";

$base = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "r", "t" ];

var_dump(compare($a, $base)); //false
var_dump(compare($b, $base)); //false
var_dump(compare($c, $base)); //false
var_dump(compare($d, $base)); //false
var_dump(compare($e, $base)); //false
var_dump(compare($f, $base)); //true
var_dump(compare($g, $base)); //false

function compare($a, $map) {
    $stringParts = explode(' ', $a);
    sort($stringParts);
    sort($map);
    return $stringParts === $map;
}
```

Comment: I think the other answer uses less resources than this.

Comment: You would think that @AdarshMohan, but there is no way to know without an explanation.

Comment: Your answer looks much better. I will accept this as the answer. thanx.

Comment: @JayBlanchard : I made that comment on the very first post. Not at all relevant for the current answer.

Comment: Why not @AdarshMohan? You said "the other answer uses less resounrces". How is that? You didn't explain how it uses less resources.

Comment: The previous post for the answer that is edited 33 min ago was using `array_map`, `explode` , `array_filter`, `foreach`, `str_split`, `implode` where `array_map` and `array_filter` are memory intensive functions where as the answer from the other person was simple enough with a `foreach`.. that's what i meant in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$a = "c d a e f b";
$b = "b e a d c f";
$c = "a b c d g e";
$d = "a b c";
$e = "abcdef";
$f = "a b c d e f g";
$g = "aabc d e f";

$array=[ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" ];

$length=strlen(str_replace(' ','',$e));


$flag=0;

foreach($array as $data){
    if (strpos($e, $data) !== false) {
        $flag=$flag+1;
    }
}

if($flag<>$length){
    echo "problem";
}
else{
    echo "working";
}
```

Here is a sample code for what you ask. If you change the strings in here `$length=strlen(str_replace(' ','',$e));`

and in here

```
if (strpos($e, $data) !== false) {
```

you will check by yourself it is working. I propose that you put those strings in an array and parse it more dynamic but that's up to you and your input.

Comment: For the section `$g` , the `strpos` will work for both the `a`s in the string which will result in a "working". but its not supposed to be in there. Anyway thanks for the idea, your answer helped me in finding the solution.

Comment: No it won't. The echo will be 'problem' for `$g` as it is supposed to. I have tested it.

Comment: sorry about that, my mistake.. I forgot to replace the `e` in `$length=strlen(str_replace(' ','',$e));`.. Your solution worked. thankz.

Comment: I am sorry this one wont work in a case. I will modify the question.. looks like its a miss interpretation.

Comment: i'm not sure that this solution can work in all the cases. for exemple it should throw wrong results with phrases that can contain each other like `['a', 'aa']` and others pitfalls

Comment: you updated the array also so for $f it should work. All the letters from the compare array are included in the $f string. What is the problem?

Comment: Why $a is false? all the letters of $a are inside the compare array. You want specific order also? That was not a part of the first question.

Comment: that's why i said `$e` is false. no combining. anyway thanks for helping, I have figured out the solution.